# Jquery index only div in td

Tags: jquery, indexing

```
$('td.tabs').on('click', 'div:not(.current)', function() {

    $("#log").prepend("<hr> Now fake Index = " + $(this).index()) ;

    $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current').parents('div.section').find('div.box').eq($(this).index() ).fadeIn(150).siblings('div.box').hide();

});
```

True Jquery Index only for `div` in `td` - how to ?

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4guru/r7y2C/)

Comment: change `... 'div:not(.current)' ...` to `... 'td>div:not(.current)' ...` to only select divs inside of td's. If that's not exactly what you want, please be more specific. Depending on the prefered behaviour, you may want to remove the `>` between `td>div`. Play arround to see the difference.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please look at this first before asking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line $("#log").prepend ... to the following:

```
$("#log").prepend("<hr> Now true Index = " + $(this).parent().children("div").index($(this)));
```

Step-by-step explanation:

1. parent() returns the parent of the current element.
2. children("div") returns all "div" elements within the parent.
3. index($(this)) returns the index of current element (clicked div) among children div.

As the result, you'll see index of the clicked div among sibling divs.

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thx! It work. 1. select tab
2. Select the checkbox for the tabs (left or right / as mutually?)
3. Summary data from tabs - only from tabs with selected checkbox